# Removing specific characters in string

Tags: bash, scripts, cp

I am currently writing a bash script and I have obtained a list of file locations. However I have notice that some file locations have spaces in the file name such as eg. : /1 2 3.txt 
Such files affects the use of commands such as cp in my case. Using "" and escaping it results in a space after the "". For e.g: " /1 2 3.txt" with a space in front of the file location, i obtained an error stating "cp: cannot stat `     /1 2 3.txt': No Such file or directory ". Is there any other method to quote a file location with "" so that the cp command can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all files containing spaces inside filenames in the new files with the same name containing underscores instead of spaces from the current directory:

```
for f in *\ *; do cp -- "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

See [BashFAQ 20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) on how to handle filenames safely.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was thinking of writing a loop to replace it but i didn't want to alter the file name. I guess I will stick to your idea as the use of quotes such as "" is affecting my file location.

Comment: i removed the for loop and used the "cp -- "$f" "${f// /_}";" it works on the cmd however when it is implemented in my bash script i received a "cp: cannot stat `       /1 2 3.txt': No such file or directory" error. Do you know why there is a large space inserted into the file location?

Comment: @pikachu See [BashFAQ 20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) on how to handle filenames safely.